# Putting/Placing a function without parenthesis inside map, filter and reduce functions in python

Tags: python, function, parentheses

why do we put a function without parenthesis inside map, filter and reduce functions? Check the code below

```
def func(n):
    return n**2
print(list(map(func,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))) # Here in this line of code func is placed inside map function without parenthesis. Why it is not put in this way map(func(),[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])?

Output: 
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
```

Comment: Because you're passing function, not the result of execution

Answer (score 1):

`map` is basically equivalent to the following (very simplified) code:

```
def map(function_object, sequence):
    return [function_object(item) for item in sequence]
```

As you can see, this `function_object` is expected to run only inside this pseudo `map` function.

Adding parentheses to a function calls that function, that's not what you want to do in this case - as you want to pass that function object into another function (`map` in this case) and tell it to work on a sequence of other items.

Any built-in function in python that requires another function as one of its arguments, like `reduce`, `filter` etc. uses the same principal.

In other words, if you were to put `func()` as in your question as an argument, `map` wouldn't get the function, it would get the result returning from that function, because it was already called. In your example that would also be an error, because `func` can't be called without arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for `map`, we can see that `map` takes a function and an iterable, and then applies the function for every item in that iterable.

If we were to add brackets to the function, so `function()` this would not pass the function object itself, but instead execute such function, and provide whatever the return for the function was.